# How to execute Java Program immediately then execute program with Job as defined

Tags: java, scheduler, quartz

I am trying to execute java program immediately then execute program with job(scheduler) as I defined in code, rightnow my scheduler is executing from 9:00 AM to 9:00 PM daily.
How can I do?

Here is my java code

```
public class FirstMainClassJob {
    
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FirstMainClassJob.class);
    
    static HelperUtl helperUtl = new HelperUtl();
    // Fire between 09AM and 09PM every day
    public static Trigger fireBetween9To9EveryDay() throws ParseException, SchedulerException, IOException {
        
        String jobTime=helperUtl.getProperty("CRON_JOB_TIME");
        
        log.info("Application running time is "+jobTime);

        JobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.newJob(GoogleDriveApiQuickstart.class).withIdentity("fireBetween9To9EveryDay", "group1").build();

        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("fireBetween9To9EveryDay", "group1")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 "+jobTime+" * * ?")).build();
        
        

        Scheduler scheduler1 = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler1.start();
        scheduler1.scheduleJob(job1, trigger);
        return trigger;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, SchedulerException, IOException {
        FirstMainClassJob.fireBetween9To9EveryDay();
    }
```

Comment: Can you restate you question. It is unclear what you want to achieve. You want your task to start immediately after application start?

Comment: @talex Thanks for reply, Yes I want to start immediately after this start on scheduler basis as I defined

Comment: Then why you need scheduler at all? Just create instance of `GoogleDriveApiQuickstart` and call its method.

Comment: my application is scheduler (hourly) base but I want to execute first time as a test like ignore scheduler, sorry for my english, hope u understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("fireOnceAtStart", "group1")
            .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withRepeatCount(1)).build();
```

to execute it once one start.

Comment: Thanks, how can I execute scheduler after this, I also mentioned I want to execute hourly basis as I defined in sample code